Should I worry because my toddler prefers sleeping on the floor?
My 2,5 year old toddler decided she wants to sleep in her own room a week ago. She has a loft bed, the lower part of which is clad in wood as a castle with a mattress in it. The upper part is locked with a door so that she cannot climb up when she is alone in the room. For several nights now, I have noticed that she is moving further and further away from her bed at night. Sometimes she lies on the threshold between the bed and the floor, sometimes she lies completely on the floor in her room. I have already placed an exercise mat in front of her bed, but she also crawls off it at night.
The floor of her room is covered with laminate and a thin carpet and seems terribly hard and uncomfortable to me, so I wonder if this is an issue worth worrying about. She seems content and wants to go back to her room every night. I'm not worried about her hurting herself as the nursery is child safe. Is this just an oddity of children or should I take action? If so, does it make sense to make it harder for her to get out of bed or does it restrict her too much? She doesn't crawl out of the normal height parents bed when she sleeps there (as she has for the last 2,5 years).

This question is similar to: 3 Year Old Wants To Sleep In Closet. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I believe there is a difference between crawling over the cold floor while sleeping and the child deciding to always seek the same spot in the closet

Sleeping on the floor is not the end of the world.  A child should be able to express themselves and do things that make them comfortable and happy, even if you think they are unusual.  So if your child really wants to sleep on the floor then that's okay and the best thing you can do is help them make their floor more comfortable to sleep on.  Trying to force them to stay in their bed is not the solution.  Restricting her freedom of expression and forcing her to do something she doesn't want to do just because you think it's more normal is not going to help your relationship with her.
That being said she may not prefer the floor so much as she doesn't like the bed, and that is a different issue.  If she sees the floor only as a less-terrible option then sleeping in the bed, instead of an option she likes, then that means she's unhappy anywhere she sleeps which isn't a good thing.  The solution still isn't to force her to stay in a bed she doesn't like, but it may be to figure out why she doesn't like the bed and fix those problems so the bed is a more ideal solution for her.  Though I stress the real goal is to simply make sure she is comfortable however she sleeps at night not to force that sleep to be in a bed as you may expect.
It's hard to know her exact motives and rather it's a preference of the floor or an active dislike for the bed.  The first obvious step would be to ask her why she does it.  In an ideal world she explains it and you adjust things to fix whatever she doesn't like about the bed, realistically she likely is too young to articulate well why she isn't using her bed.  You can help with that though by asking her simple yes and no questions.  It's much easier to say 'yes' or 'no' to a question then to try to figure out how to explain an open ended question like "why don't you like this" when you're that young.  So some sample questions you might ask are

do you like your bed?  (followed a little later by do you dislike your bed.  With a kid that young the second question is not redundant, it's not unheard of that you get a yes or no with both of them.)
Do you like sleeping on the floor?

The next questions would be shifted a bit based off of rather she expresses more that she likes sleeping on the floor or that she dislikes her bed.  You should ask why she likes the floor if she stresses liking the floor, or why she dislikes the bed if that's what she stresses, but you can still ask the same general questions.

Is you're bed too hot (floors suck heat out much faster then a bed does if you're hot)
Is your bed scary?
Is you're bed too big?
Is you're bed too dark?
Is you're bed too high?
Do you have trouble getting in you're bed after getting out?
Are you playing when you sleep on the floor (she may be pretending or involved in imaginative play when she moves to the floor, then just falls asleep because she is tired)

Ideally you get a clear yes or no to one of these questions, or similar ones, which tells you exactly what her problem is, then you can look to fix whatever she doesn't like.  Though again it's quite possible you won't get a useful response even with more direct questions.
In that case it's time to experiment, because what could go wrong with experimenting on your own children?  If you have another bed you can try asking if she would rather have it in her room, and if she says yes try swapping them out.  Maybe let her try sleeping in your guest room, or get out sleeping bags and 'camp out' on the floor, or bring the couch pillows into her room and sleep on them, or just sleep on the couch.  Try a few temporary sleeping arrangements, suggesting them as a fun/novel alternative to get her excited about trying it, and see if there are any she seems to really like.  If you can identify what she most likes you may be better able to identify how the bed fails to meet her needs.
Finally if all else fails, put a mattress and some blankets down on the floor as well and let her sleep in either spot.  Again sleeping on the floor is not the end of the world, the only possible harm is that it may be uncomfortable.  So make the floor sleeping option more comfortable for her and let her sleep there if she want's.  In fact if she consistently sleeps on a floor mattress and never uses the bed you might even consider moving the bed out of her room to free up space for awhile and let her tell you when she wants to try having a bed again.  Or if her room is large enough leave both in her room and she will naturally transition to using the bed more over time as she gets older.
The point is as long as she has some way she is comfortable sleeping the exact method doesn't matter.  You're only goal is to find the most comfortable option for her, even if for the time being that means sleeping on a mat on the floor.  Give her lots of options she may like more, try to communicate with her, but also give her the freedom to pick what out of those options she most likes!

Thanks for the answer, I really like the guide to questioning a toddler.
